# EF6:Parent context null inside same child query

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework-6

My database contains below table in parent child relationships:-

Gender->Audit->Request(All are in 1:N Relationships)

I want to fetch all Genders with corresponding requests from database.
My viewmodel looks like below:-

```
public class GenderViewModel
    {
        public string GenderId { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }       
        public List<RequestNumberViewModel> OldRequestNumber { get; set; }
    }
```

I have written below LINQ Query syntax to achieve this.

```
List<GenderViewModel> vmGender = (from g in ctxGetGender.genders 
                            select new GenderViewModel
                            {
                                GenderId = g.org_genderid,
                                Name = g.org_gendername,                                    
                                OldRequestNumber = (from egender in ctxGetGender.genders
                                                    join audit in ctxGetGender.audits
                                                    on new { f1 = egender.org_genderid, f2 = tableName } equals new { f1 = audit.org_keydataid, f2 = audit.org_audittabletype } into temp
                                                    from audit in temp.DefaultIfEmpty()
                                                    join req in ctxGetGender.eventrequestworkflows
                                                    on audit.org_requestid equals req.org_eventreqworkflowid into reqtemp
                                                    from req in reqtemp.DefaultIfEmpty()
                                                    where egender.org_genderid == g.org_genderid
                                                    select new RequestNumberViewModel
                                                    {                                                           
                                                        RequestId = req.org_eventreqworkflowid,
                                                        RequestNumber = req.org_siterequestnumber
                                                    }).Distinct().ToList()
                            }).ToList();
```

When I try to run this query I got the below error:-

> Object reference not set to an instance.

After some analysis I found that when I comment the below line then the query is working fine. However it is not giving the required result:-

> where egender.org_genderid == g.org_genderid

I found out that "g.org_genderid" is coming as null and so basically I am getting the error.

Can you please help me as why parent context is becoming null in child subquery?

**Call Stack**

```
   at MySql.Data.EntityFramework.SelectStatement.AddColumn(ColumnFragment column, Scope scope)
   at MySql.Data.EntityFramework.SelectGenerator.Visit(DbApplyExpression expression)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Common.CommandTrees.DbApplyExpression.Accept[TResultType](DbExpressionVisitor`1 visitor)
   at MySql.Data.EntityFramework.SqlGenerator.VisitInputExpression(DbExpression e, String name, TypeUsage type)
   at MySql.Data.EntityFramework.SelectGenerator.VisitInputExpressionEnsureSelect(DbExpression e, String name, TypeUsage type)
   at MySql.Data.EntityFramework.SelectGenerator.Visit(DbProjectExpression expression)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Common.CommandTrees.DbProjectExpression.Accept[TResultType](DbExpressionVisitor`1 visitor)
   at MySql.Data.EntityFramework.SqlGenerator.VisitInputExpression(DbExpression e, String name, TypeUsage type)
   at MySql.Data.EntityFramework.SelectGenerator.VisitInputExpressionEnsureSelect(DbExpression e, String name, TypeUsage type)
   at MySql.Data.EntityFramework.SelectGenerator.Visit(DbUnionAllExpression expression)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Common.CommandTrees.DbUnionAllExpression.Accept[TResultType](DbExpressionVisitor`1 visitor)
   at MySql.Data.EntityFramework.SqlGenerator.VisitInputExpression(DbExpression e, String name, TypeUsage type)
   at MySql.Data.EntityFramework.SelectGenerator.VisitInputExpressionEnsureSelect(DbExpression e, String name, TypeUsage type)
   at MySql.Data.EntityFramework.SelectGenerator.Visit(DbSortExpression expression)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Common.CommandTrees.DbSortExpression.Accept[TResultType](DbExpressionVisitor`1 visitor)
   at MySql.Data.EntityFramework.SqlGenerator.VisitInputExpression(DbExpression e, String name, TypeUsage type)
   at MySql.Data.EntityFramework.SelectGenerator.VisitInputExpressionEnsureSelect(DbExpression e, String name, TypeUsage type)
   at MySql.Data.EntityFramework.SelectGenerator.Visit(DbProjectExpression expression)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Common.CommandTrees.DbProjectExpression.Accept[TResultType](DbExpressionVisitor`1 visitor)
   at MySql.Data.EntityFramework.SelectGenerator.GenerateSQL(DbCommandTree tree)
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlProviderServices.CreateDbCommandDefinition(DbProviderManifest providerManifest, DbCommandTree commandTree)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Common.DbProviderServices.CreateDbCommandDefinition(DbProviderManifest providerManifest, DbCommandTree commandTree, DbInterceptionContext interceptionContext)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Common.DbProviderServices.CreateCommandDefinition(DbCommandTree commandTree, DbInterceptionContext interceptionContext)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.Internal.EntityCommandDefinition..ctor(DbProviderFactory storeProviderFactory, DbCommandTree commandTree, DbInterceptionContext interceptionContext, IDbDependencyResolver resolver, BridgeDataReaderFactory bridgeDataReaderFactory, ColumnMapFactory columnMapFactory)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.Internal.EntityProviderServices.CreateDbCommandDefinition(DbProviderManifest providerManifest, DbCommandTree commandTree, DbInterceptionContext interceptionContext)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Common.DbProviderServices.CreateCommandDefinition(DbCommandTree commandTree, DbInterceptionContext interceptionContext)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.Internal.ObjectQueryExecutionPlanFactory.CreateCommandDefinition(ObjectContext context, DbQueryCommandTree tree)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.Internal.ObjectQueryExecutionPlanFactory.Prepare(ObjectContext context, DbQueryCommandTree tree, Type elementType, MergeOption mergeOption, Boolean streaming, Span span, IEnumerable`1 compiledQueryParameters, AliasGenerator aliasGenerator)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ELinqQueryState.GetExecutionPlan(Nullable`1 forMergeOption)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.<>c__DisplayClass41_0.<GetResults>b__1()
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.ExecuteInTransaction[T](Func`1 func, IDbExecutionStrategy executionStrategy, Boolean startLocalTransaction, Boolean releaseConnectionOnSuccess)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.<>c__DisplayClass41_0.<GetResults>b__0()
   at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DefaultExecutionStrategy.Execute[TResult](Func`1 operation)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.GetResults(Nullable`1 forMergeOption)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.<System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<T>.GetEnumerator>b__31_0()
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyEnumerator`1.MoveNext()
   at System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
   at Application.Business.BLL.BusinessLayer.GenderBLL.GetAllGenders(String tableName) in G:\onMyTune\IP\MySQL Projects\Project Acceleration - Employee Web API\Application.Business\BLL\BusinessLayer\GenderBLL.cs:line 61
   at Application.WebAPI.Controllers.GenderController.GetAllGenders() in G:\onMyTune\IP\MySQL Projects\Project Acceleration - Employee Web API\Project Acceleration - Employee Web API\Controllers\GenderController.cs:line 120
```

**Observation**
This query worked fine when SQL Server is in backend. I checked that. When I am moving with exact same table schema to MySQL then this query start giving exceptions.

Comment: The database is not retuning any values.  So first add checks to make sure you do not get exceptions when a query doesn't return anything.  Second check the type of genderid in database and see if  the id is a integer or string.  Often ids fail because the wrong type is being used.  An integer will not compare with a string value.

Comment: Could it be the way that the OldRequestNumber query is interpreted and it doesn't know about 'g' at all rather than the value of org_genderid being null. Have you tried using GenderId in its place?

Comment: Hi @jdweng, When there is no data in database then also I am getting same exceptions which is gone when I comment the line as mentioned in the post. Second is that "where" compares same "org_genderid" column in table "gender". Column is of type string.

Comment: Hi @Catherine, when I am using GenderId  in the place of "org_genderid" like here in next line then it is not compiling. "where egender.org_genderid == GenderId". Can you let me know if I am doing anything wrong here?

Comment: It is possible that some  "g.org_genderid" values in the database are null.  So you need to add another part of the where to avoid the nulls  : "where (egender.org_genderid != null) && (egender.org_genderid == GenderId)

Comment: org_genderid is the primary key of table Gender. It cannot be null if Gender contains data. If I put this condition then where clause will be bypassed as g is coming as null always.

Comment: Hi @simpleuser. Using GenderId was just a thing to try/rule out. Sorry it wasn't more useful and prevented compiling.

Comment: Does storing your id using `let gid = g.org_genderid` right after `from g in ctxGetGender.genders` and using it for the comparison like `where egender.org_genderid == gid` does any difference?

Comment: No. This is not making difference. I have added call stack in the post for your reference.

Comment: @simpleuser first of all, why the JOINs? It's the ORM's job to generate JOIN clauses from the relations between entities. None of those JOINs should be there. You didn't post your entities or tables so one has to guess what's going on in these JOINs or post a correct LINQ query.

Comment: @simpleuser the fact the stack trace is trying to construct a UNION though means that either the LINQ engine got confused by this query or the query doesn't match the requirements. I'm confused by it as well. Perhaps nested query ends up referencing the outer one, resulting in a recursive query? That's how you could end up with a `UNION` in a `Select`

Comment: Yes...This is inner Query referencing outer query..Is it not possible using Entity Framework?

Comment: This query work fine when SQL Server used as backend but start giving exceptions when MySQL is used as backend. Any idea why is it happening?

Comment: Are you renaming it? Is that the issue? What is gender for anyways? You start the query: `from g in ctxGetGender.genders` and then define egender later as: `from egender in ctxGetGender.genders` So I'm not sure if you're overwriting g by redefining the source, but even if you're not I don't get the point of the following comparison: `where egender.org_genderid == g.org_genderid`.

Answer (score 0):

mysql and oracle doesn't support linq query
better to try it with sqlserver it will work fine
if you wanna use mysql then try ADO.NET Entity Framework

Answer (score 0):

Finally I got solution. Below Linq Query helped me in getting the desired result. Compare my below query with old query mentioned in the post then you get to know the difference. Please let me know your feedback.

```
vmGender = (from g in ctxGetGender.genders
                            let gReqID = (from egender in ctxGetGender.genders
                                          join audit in ctxGetGender.audits                                          
                                          on new { f1 = egender.org_genderid, f2 = tableName } equals new { f1 = audit.org_keydataid.Value, f2 = audit.org_audittabletype } into temp                                         
                                          from audit in temp.DefaultIfEmpty()
                                          join req in ctxGetGender.eventrequestworkflows
                                          on audit.org_requestid equals req.org_eventreqworkflowid into reqtemp
                                          from req in reqtemp.DefaultIfEmpty()
                                          select new RequestNumberViewModel
                                          {                                              
                                              KeyId = egender.org_genderid,
                                              RequestId = req.org_eventreqworkflowid,
                                              RequestNumber = req.org_siterequestnumber
                                          }).Distinct().ToList()
                            select new GenderViewModel
                            {
                                GenderId = g.org_genderid,
                                Name = g.org_gendername,                                   
                                OldRequestNumber = gReqID.Where(x => x.KeyId.HasValue && x.KeyId.Value == g.org_genderid).ToList()                                                                
                            }).ToList();
```